# USB-C hub with HDMI output not working

Tags: video, hdmi, usb-c

I recently bought a USB-C hub (QGeeM USB C Hub Multiport Adapter, 7 in 1) that has a HDMI port so I can use two monitors with my Thinkpad E15.

For some reason it's not being auto-detected and I can't turn the monitor on.

xrandr and lsusb output;

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.06 +  48.04  
   1680x1050     60.06  
   1280x1024     60.06  
   1440x900      60.06  
   1280x800      60.06  
   1280x720      60.06  
   1024x768      60.06  
   800x600       60.06  
   640x480       60.06  
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 119.98    99.93    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 06cb:00da Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b6be Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 25a4:9311  
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 3443:930f  
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 1532:0084 Razer USA, Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 04b4:0510 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I log `dmesg` when I plug in the hub I do get something like looks like a video input;

```
[  287.589762] usb 1-1.4.4: Product: USB C Video Adaptor      
[  287.589764] usb 1-1.4.4: Manufacturer: USB C  
[  287.589767] usb 1-1.4.4: SerialNumber: 000000000001
```

According to thinkpad they do support HDMI through USB-C hub. So I am not sure why it's not being detected.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski yeah it just turned out to be an issue with which cable was connected to what.

and by the I mean I wasn't connecting the cables up correctly. Everything works fine now.

Comment: I've got this HOCO 5 in 1 USB-C hub which includes HDMI. Its high end, I paid like 50 dollars for it and was reccomanded it by some guy on reddit. I did everything I know and it still wont read the HDMI in xrandr. It does work for my RJ-45 ethernet, for all USB ports just wont read the HDMI. 

Im running arch linux with an NVIDIA card. Ive tried to use the integrated card too but it didnt resolve the issue. I really dont know what at this point :/

Comment: i wish i knew enough to help you. i remember when i searched there was some information. if its arch linux i would post on boards specific to that. people are usually quite helpful in running the commands to diagnose it.